# Importing mdb to AWS RDS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I have a small and very old access DB, it is just one .mdb file and it was made before Access 2003.

How can I import it to SQL server running on AWS RDS? I actually only need to import one table from it which has around 600 rows.

Comment: I don't know that AWS would support importing an Access database - did you contact AWS support? I would say install SQL Server Express locally, and use the upsizing wizard. Then you should be able to hook SQL Server up to it just fine.

Comment: If you simply need a single table imported to a SQL Server table on AWS, why not use Access to export the table as a .CSV, then import that?